# Parents not understanding

Tags: shirk

Assalamo Alaikum
If the parents of the person forcibly make him listen to music in the car is the person to be blamed? 
And when im hearing soke music unintentionally which contains shirk, am i a mushrik? The thing is im praying 5 times a day but day by day im discovering a new sin of me and I repent but some of the things I cant repent of like listening to songs with shirk, 
Also am i obeying my parents instead of ALLAH when in the car and listening to music? Keep in mind I dont want to and have explained to them but they dont understand.

Answer (score 2):

Wa Alaikum As Salam WrWb.

Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) said, ‏ إن الله وضع عن أمتي الخطأ والنسيان وما استكرهوا عليه (Allah has forgiven my nation for mistakes and forgetfulness, and what they are forced to do) - [Ibn Majah (2045)](https://sunnah.com/urn/1263640). A person who is forced to listen to music, which he otherwise hates and would not allow if things were in his control, is then not under any sin. And merely listening to music that contains shirk doesn't make a person a Mushrik.. unless they start agreeing with it. But if you reject it and try to ignore it, then you're fine.

I would be more worried about your parents. Continue to teach them and guide them away towards correct conduct. Music itself is scripturally wrong to listen to, but coupled with lyrics containing Shirk makes it a lot worse.